# Dynamic binding sources for a wpf application

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding

I am looking for some advice about how to build an wpf application, in C#.

We currently have five sql databases (2005) all with same data structure (tables, fields and views etc.), however they are named differently (A,L,M,T 0). I am trying to use the model of having an interface project and data access project as I would like to keep using the work from the data access project for other projects / screens.

I have succesffully created projects to update the data from one of the databases based on data sets, sql classes or entity frameworks.

I would now like to make one window, in which you choose from a combo box the datasource you wish to update and the window data souce is then set and for example the supplier data is displayed on the form and can be updated.

I can think of building a method, which based on the selected value in the combo, that looks up the connection string and creates a supplier object and then this object is bound to the window controls.

I have also looked at collection view sources, but can not see an straight forward method of how to set this dynamically

What is the best method to choose of what I am calling "run time" binding. Of course am links and examples would be great.

Comment: You don't need any "runtime binding", whatever that means. What you need is a proper ViewModel that can expose the data needed to be displayed in the UI, and then you can populate that ViewModel with whatever data coming from whatever data source you want.

Comment: Sorry "run time binding"  was trying to get over the the fact the decision about the datasource was choosen by the user. I do not have a deep knowledge of the basic principles of object orientated programming. I have looked at a couple of MVVM articles you suggested in some early posts and googled the subject, I get the principle. My only comment is MVVM seems a bit complicated for what by your standards is a very simple update appliocation. However I may try and work through the principle as way of expanding my limited knowledge and skills, can you suggest any other good "simple" tutorials?

Comment: [This](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) is an outstanding series of articles by Reed Copsey, explaining the mindshift needed when moving from, say Winforms, into WPF and MVVM.

Comment: At first glance, MVVM might seem like it "requires more code", but you will quickly realize it's actually the opposite. In the end, it's just simple, simple properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, versus a lot of boilerplate needed to pass data between UI and the rest of the application, as usually found in other paradigms. Also, in MVVM you abstract the UI, thus there's no need to manipulate any UI elements (which are actually complex classes with complex behaviors and life-cycles) in code.

Comment: Many thanks I shall have a read